# Upserting large reference (dimension) table

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I was looking for a way to upsert a large dimension table (10M rows).

- Using **Lookup Transformation with Full Cache** is not an option from memory usage point of view + I have duplicate values in source.
- Using **Lookup Transformation without Cache** is not the best option from performance point of view.

Do I have any other option?

Comment: Transfer to a staging table in your warehouse, and UPSERT using SQL statements (probably MERGE) using execute SQL task.

Comment: @GarethD: what about the case when other transformations should be applied? They should be applied on staging table and then perform the MERGE operation?

Comment: Is File Cache an option in this case?

Comment: It really depends on what the transformations are, some can be performed within SSIS, but I would be inclined to do the majority of transformations on the staging table as you have said. When dealing with 10m rows, I'd guess that SQL Tasks are going to out perform SSIS tasks.

Comment: @GarethD: it's about classical business key => surrogate key transformations.

Comment: Yes, do the lookup on the staging table, this can be handled with a simple join, which will be more efficient on 10m rows than a lookup transformation.